# mount grub partition

Tags: boot, 13.04, grub2

I'm pretty new to Linux. I am trying to make a dedicated partition for bootloader called grub2. I am following [this](http://www.xente.mundo-r.com/zasjls/lhs/computer/grub.html) tutorial and I'm stuck at step 5.

> Exit GParted and mount the new Grub partition. 'Places → Grub.' A new
>   icon called Grub should show up on your desktop and its corresponding
>   window should open.

it should be mounted under /media/partitionname I think.

I'm trying this with a 14.04 Ubuntu live CD

Comment: ok, what's the problem?

Comment: You can right click -> mount the partition in GParted.

Answer (score 1):

This tutorial is really a bad idea.  You do not want to have a normally unmounted grub partition where you have to manually write your own grub config file that will not be automatically updated when new kernels are installed, and will break when grub is upgraded.  If you want a separate /boot partition, you need to keep it mounted in /boot, it needs to be significantly larger ( at least 100 mb, preferably 200 ), and it should use ext4 instead of the antiquated ext2 filesystem.  You will need to edit your /etc/fstab to mount it in /boot ( you can look up the uuid with `sudo blkid` and follow the template of the existing entries in fstab ), and then mount it with `sudo mount /boot`.  After that you want to run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure grub-pc` to reinstall grub to the mbr of your boot drive, and then run `sudo update-grub` to generate the config file.

You also do all of this from the installed system, not the live cd.

Comment: I used to do a separate grub partition with grub legacy. But then you used chain loading and installed each grub to a PBR - partition boot sector. But grub2 does not fit in a PBR, so chain loading does not work well. And grub2 has a much better os-prober than old grub legacy. Better to just have grub in the main working install you use to be the one grub that boots everything.